# AEM Magento Integration sample project ,cart icon is missing and the below error is coming in the console

Tags: magento, aem

The integration with magento was done and the categories and products are showing up. However, the shopping cart icon is missing and the below errors were observed :

POST http://localhost:4502/magento/graphql 403 (Forbidden)         (anonymous) @ react-components.js:16

react-components.js:16 Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

react-components.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

Cart will not be even visible until and unless you do not setup a dispatcher as shown here in this [video](https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/commerce-integration-framework/tutorials.html#!AdobeDocs/commerce-cif-documentation/master/tutorials/03-shopping-cart-dispatcher.md). The mini cart is actually a react component which directly communicates with Back-end Magento and to avoid CORS issue you have to set up proxy through a Dispatcher.

Comment: video is not available anymore at the given link, is there a new one?